# подключение файла в функции, не видит переменной

Tags: php

Использую ооп.

Есть такой класс

```
class Users extends BaseController{

public function getUser( $u_id ){
    $this->a = 12;
    $a = 13;

    if( !$u_id ){
        return $this->getPage404();// 33 строка
    }
}
```

Функция getPage404();

```
class BaseController{

    public function getPage404( $u_id ){
        include '/404.php';
    }
}
```

Вот когда я пытаюсь подключить файл если некорректный ид юзера

> return $this->getPage404();

Я в файле 404.php пытаюсь вывести

```
echo $a;// NULL
echo $this->a;// 12
```

Но, если я подключаю файл на 33й строке не через функцию, а напрямую через include:

```
if( !$u_id ){
    return include '/404.php';// 33 строка
}
```

В таком случае, в файле 404.php у меня выводит нормально все

```
 echo $a;// 13
    echo $this->a;// 12
```

Вопрос. При подключении через функцию "getPage404", у меня получается для файла 404.php область видимости метода getPage404?

Comment: без `return` пробовали подключать?

Comment: в идеале хорошо бы указать абсолютный путь до файла `404.php`

Comment: путь правильный, это я для теста написал.

Comment: @mix да, пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

Понял в чем беда. Из документации

> Когда файл включается, его код наследует ту же область видимости переменых, что и строка, на которой произошло включение.

На момент подключения файла, в функции нет переменной $a, так как эта переменная была объявлена в другой функции.

2 варианта решения

1. Передавать параметрами в функцию(метод) переменные.
2. Через $this->a = 15;

Answer (score 0):

Вы возвращаете функцию return $this->getPage404();

А на прямую вы возвращаете содержимое файла   return $this->getPage404();

```
public function getPage404( $u_id ){
        return include '/404.php';
    }
```

Comment: Если так сделать, то вернет "1", типо успешное подключение файла, но не вернет содержимое. Так как include - не зачитывает файл, а исполняет его.